# getting month name wrong with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am having problem with this small piece of code

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss");

String str = "2010-03-13 01:01:22";

Date date = sf.parse(str);

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy hh:mm aaa");

System.out.println(" Date " + f.format(date));
```

Output :

```
 Date 13 Jan 2010 01:01 AM
```

The code seems to be fine but still I am getting month name wrong.
Please help !!
Thanks.

Comment: Be careful forcing the format of dates. What happens when your app goes global!?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are using minute instead of month in your pattern. It should be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Answer (score 8):

`mm` stands for minute. You should use `MM` when parsing month:

```
SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```